# Table cell pattern of colors

Tags: tables, color

With `\cellcolor` one can set the background color of a cell.

I use this in documenting a communication protocol to indicate the type of the value in a certain field, say green is type X and blue is type Y.

Now I have arrived at a situation where the type of a field depends on the value of another field. So in my table, I want to somehow put both colors in the field, meaning the value could be either of types X and Y.

I imagine it would be quite hard to have a generic multi-color pattern as the background color, but would it at least be possible to divide up the cell and set the color to each part differently?

Here is a simple example of what I'm trying to achieve as the background of a single cell in the table:

[image]

Comment: If you willing to draw table for example with TikZ package, than you have possibilities to color each cell (determined as rectangle shape) on many ways. Also in the way as you show in picture in your question.

Comment: @Zarko, in that case, I could just make the table with inkscape and import the svg. But I was thinking more in line of whether some magic with `multicolumn` and `multirow` would work.

Comment: do this in table you really need a magic ... If table is not huge, is worth to draw it. Since you didn't provide an (dummy)  example of your table, I can not to give you a some idea, hot to simply make it in TikZ (for example as matrix).

Comment: The table has multiple arguments, it is a communication protocol. I have a macro that generates the table, given certain parameters I give it, such as colors of certain fields in the communication message. It wouldn't make sense to generate the whole table with TikZ, since I have multiple commands that would require double-color as above and each have it at possibly different fields.

Comment: So, if TikZ would work, it should be able to work as a single cell of a table generated by some other macro. Otherwise the duplicate work is just not worth coloring the cell!

Comment: I can only guessing. You have all data and know what you like. Decision is up to you. Maybe someone else know how to color table cells as you like to do. By the way, I successfully draw many communication protocols by us of TikZ package.

Comment: Is the coloring supposed to be automatic or manual? Because the solutions would be way different.

Comment: Manual. Right now, I do something like `\Message{..}..{\TYPEX value}..{..}`, to tell the color of the field. Something along those lines where I could say `\TYPEXY value` or `\TYPEXY{value}` would be great.